# how to get href from within element using php and simple html dom

Tags: php, element, simple-html-dom

I have an html page that looks a bit like this

```
xxxx
<a href="www.google.com">google!</a>

<div class="big-div">
    <a href="http://www.url.com/123" title="123">
    <div class="little-div">xxx</div></a>

    <a href="http://www.url.com/456" title="456">
    <div class="little-div">xxx</div></a>
</div>
xxxx
```

I am trying to pull of the href's out of the big-div.  I can get all the href's out of the whole page by using code like below.

```
$links = $html->find ('a');
foreach ($links as $link) 
{
    echo $link->href.'<br>';
}
```

But how do I get only the href's within the div "big-div".
Edit:
I think I got it.  For those that care:

```
foreach ($html->find('div[class=big-div]') as $element) {
            $links = $element->find('a');
            foreach ($links as $link) {
                echo $link->href.'<br>';
            }
        }
```

Comment: find big-div first, then find the links in that object

Comment: that's what i'm asking how to do!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) is useful:

```
$html->find(".big-div")->find('a');
```

And then proceed to get the `href` and whatever other attributes you are interested in.

**Edit:** The above would be the general idea. I've never used Simple HTML DOM, so perhaps you need to tweak the syntax somewhat. Try:

```
foreach($html->find('.big-div') as $bigDiv) {
   $link = $bigDiv->find('a');
   echo $link->href . '<br>';
}
```

or perhaps:

```
$bigDivs = $html->find('.big-div');

foreach($bigDivs as $div) {
    $link = $div->find('a');
    echo $link->href . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: who needs documentation when people can write code for you though :p

Comment: When I try this - Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object.

Answer (score 0):

Quick flip - put this in your foreach

```
$image = $html->find('.big-div')->href;
```